# Align imageview to top

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I have JPGs of various sizes.

I created a custom listview with an imageview and two textviews.

I want to align the imageview to the top left of the LinearLayout, but nothing I have tried everything, but nothing works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/petPhoto"
       android:layout_gravity="top|left"
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <LinearLayout
       android:background="#ff0000"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/petName"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/petDescription"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Change your LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and add the alignParentTop property to top,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:background="@color/card_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:src="@drawable/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="72dip"
        android:layout_height="72dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Card title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Card description"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Small"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output of your code like this,**

[image]

Comment: No, does not work. The imageview is now appearing in the center. It also is not algned to the top of each "row" of the listview.  I want the imageview on the left - aligned to the top and left corner.

Comment: I have edited the imageview, please check this and I have inserted the property, alignParentLeft="true"

Comment: For better reference, please share your pic that how you need it, so I can guide you as per the snapshot.

Comment: I don't know how to post a screenshot from my smartphone.  I am working with three JPGs: (1) 448 x 280,  (2) 336 x 418, (3) 372 x 336.  With your latest edit, the imageview and the textviews are all vertical. The JPGs are all centered in the 150dp x 150dp. So for #1, there is padding at top and bottom, for #2, there is padding on the left and right, for #3 there is padding at the top and bottom.

Comment: So. what's the issue buddy, tell me.

Comment: The issue is the imageview is centered both horizontally and vertically in the first "cell". The "cell" being the textviews. I essentially want a 2 cells of a grid. First cell has the imageview and the second cell has the textviews. I want the imageview to align to the top and left. I tried your code and others, the imageview is not aligning to the top left corner of the "cell".

Comment: Try the above answer that was edited by me just now and I have attached a snapshot of this, so you can get the better idea for this.

Comment: I found the only way to get the images to work out right is to make them all the same size in the JPG files. Try your code when the thumbnails are of different sizes proportionally. For example, thumbnail #1 is 150x150 and thumbnail #2 is  300x400. You will see what I mean.

Comment: After Googling some more, the solution was to use  android:scaleType="fitStart" for the ImageView. This aligns the JPG to the top left corner

Comment: You need the same thing into the above snapshot which was sent by me?

Comment: Yes. I need the android:scaleType="fitStart".   It is because my ImageView is set for layout of 150 x 150, but my JPGs are not all the same sizes as I wrote aboout above.